# Python: How to create a auto complete search bar from list of countries in a JSON file with flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a simple JSON file which has a list of country names, and a simple HTML page with just an input box and a submit button. When a user types in a country, it just returns the country name back to the user, How would I go about creating an autocomplete search bar with the list of countries I have in my JSON file, allowing the user to know what countries are available to search?

I was thinking, as the user types the 3rd letter of the country and drop down menu with related countries display under the search bar.

*.json

```
{
    "flags": [
{
 "country": [
  {
   "name": "Afghanistan",
   "flag": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.wpr.com/flag-pages/png250/af.png"
  },
  {
   "name": "Åland Islands",
   "flag": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.wpr.com/flag-pages/png250/ax.png"
  },
  {
   "name": "Albania",
   "flag": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.wpr.com/flag-pages/png250/al.png"
  },
  {
   "name": "Algeria",
   "flag": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.wpr.com/flag-pages/png250/dz.png"
  }
{
```

*.html

```
<div class="background" >
         <h1 id="MainTitle">INFO EARTH</h1>
         <div id="main" class="form-group">
            <form action="#" method="POST">
               <div id='Wrapper' class="card-body">
                  <input type="text" name="UI"  id="textbox" class="form-control"  placeholder = "Enter a country...">
                  <div id="button">
                     <button id="click" type="submit" name="submit" value="search" >
                        <p id='headingText'><i class="fa fa-search"></i></p>
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </form>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
            <br>
         </div>
         {% block data%}
         {% endblock%}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend embedding the json as a js file.
Then any page can import it and it doesn't have to be parsed to a JS object.

Creating a dropdown requires you making a list which appears under the input field. And you have to filter out the countries that don't match the entered string. It requires a lot of javascript.

I recommend looking at this example by w3 schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can send a request to the backend on every keystroke (or button click or whatever event) which filters through your JSON file and return only the relevant results; which you can render to page using javascript and DOM manipulation.

```py
@app.route('/filter/<keyword>')
def simpleFilter(keyword):
    # case-sensitive / startsWith given keyword
    erg = filter(lambda x : x["name"].startswith(keyword), d["flags"][0]["country"])
    return jsonify(list(erg))
```

Sending a `GET` request like this `http://localhost:5000/filter/A` should returns:

```json
[
  {
    "flag": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.wpr.com/flag-pages/png250/af.png", 
    "name": "Afghanistan"
  }, 
  {
    "flag": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.wpr.com/flag-pages/png250/al.png", 
    "name": "Albania"
  }, 
  {
    "flag": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.wpr.com/flag-pages/png250/dz.png", 
    "name": "Algeria"
  }
]
```

You have complete freedom on how to call that endpoint from your frontend. Either using `XMLHttpRequest`, `jQuery` or the new `fetch` API.